# Grouping and Ordering Semi Written Lambda Query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, lambda

```
public class Car
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name{get;set;}
    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type{get;set;}
}

public class CarOwner
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name{get;set;}
    [JsonProperty("gender")]
    public string Gender{get;set;}
    [JsonProperty("age")]
    public int Age{get;set;}
    [JsonProperty("cars")]
    public List<Car> Cars{get;set;}
}

public class Result
{
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public List<string> Name { get; set; }
}
```

What I have tried:

```
var z = m.Where(b => b.Cars != null).Select(k => new Result{Gender = 
k.Gender, Name = k.Cars.Where(t => t.Type.Contains("Heavy")).Select(h => 
h.Name).ToList()});
```

I need to group by gender and display all names of cars under it in alphabetically sorted order. e..g

Male:
Ambassador (sorted albhabetically)
Lamborghini
Maruti

Female :
Bugatti (sorted alphabetically)
Maruti
Scooty

Comment: Please find the JSOn structure:

Comment: First of all make your Gender an enum

Answer (score 0):

You already know what you need to do, and this is exactly what you need.

```
 var res = owners
             .GroupBy(o => o.Gender)
             .Select(r => new Result
         {
             Gender = r.Key,
             Name = r
             .SelectMany(co => co.Cars)
             .Select(c => c.Name)
             .OrderBy(car => car).ToList()
         });
```

Comment: Thank you Bpse_geek. One small help where to put this piece of code. is it with the z variabale? var z = m.Where(b => b.Cars != null).Select(k => new Result{Gender = 
k.Gender, Name = k.Cars.Where(t => t.Type.Contains("Heavy")).Select(h => 
h.Name).ToList()});

Comment: Replace your LINQ With the one I provided. owners variable here is the list of owners. List<CarOwners>

Comment: I would suggest you go through the LINQ concept overall. Here is the link you can start with - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/getting-started-with-linq

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object error. Because one of the cars has null and had to be handled.

Comment: I would not be aware of all the edge cases and all your use cases, So those you need to take care. Mark this as an answer if this logic works for you. Thanks

Comment: Bose_geek: I will go through it. But earnestly thank you for your help.

Comment: @somnathroy - If this worked for you, Kindly mark this as answer. Thanks